# Lombok SuperBuilder Spring Autowire Issue With Child Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, lombok

I have a parent class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@SuperBuilder
@Service
public class Parent {}
```

And a child class:

```
@Profile("integration")
@SuperBuilder
@Service
public class Child extends Parent {}
```

I am using this child class only in an integration test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {
            ...
            Child.class,
            ...
        })
@ActiveProfiles({"integration"})
class ITTest {
    @Autowired
    private Child child;
}
```

When I try to run my integration test, I'm having problem on loading application context:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> '...service.integration.interfaces.Child$ChildBuilder'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Parent class is in under main, child class and integration tests are under test package.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Although it's a long shot, it's well worth trying: there is another issue that prevents Child beans from loading, and what we see here is only the result. Take a closer look at all the log prints from the moment the server starts up.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue:

I removed the whole @SuperBuilder and implemented constructor by myself. Also used default application context, so removed classes from @SpringBootTest:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class Parent {}


@Service
public class Child extends Parent {

      public Child() {
         super();
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
class ITTest {
    @Autowired
    private Child child;
}
```

It automatically autowired the correct bean.